# how to customize cookie in express?

Tags: node.js, session, cookies

I am using `express-session` in my project:

```
app.use(session({
  name: "server-session-cookie-id",
  secret: 'express secret',
  maxAge: 1000 * 3600 * 24,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: true,
  store: new RedisStore({client: redisClient, ttl: 260, db: 2}),
}))
```

`express-session` will generate a cookie named `server-session-cookie-id` when I first visit my application.

But, in my situation I want to append some information in cookie, something like this:

```
cookie['server-session-cookie-id'] + uuid
```

how can I change the cookie when the cookie first time generate?

---

EDIT

I think I ask the wrong question, what I want is when first visit my application(any page), I just create a cookie named `uuid`.

Comment: Why use a uuid on the cookie?  The cookie is already unique to that specific connecting browser.

Comment: @jfriend00 I think I just ask the wrong question, I want to add another cookie named `uuid`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a cookie using `res.cookie` and `node-uuid`.

`npm install node-uuid --save`

`var uuid = require('uuid');`

Then in your middleware of your main application just check for a `user` object:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.user) {
        res.cookie('uuid', uuid.v4());
    }
    next();
}
```

Assuming you have a `user` object on the `req` request object in the case of using `express-session` with `passport`.

Comment: I want to change content of cookie['server-session-cookie-id'], are you  changing the name of 'server-session-cookie-id'?

Comment: I've posted an updated answer so you can modify the content of the cookie using `genid` from `express-session`.

Comment: I am sorry, I think I just ask the wrong question, what I want is when user first visit my application(any page), I just create a cookie named `uuid`.

Comment: Okay I have edited the code above so you can set it in your middleware by checking for the user and using `res.cookie`.

Answer (score 0):

If you really just want to set a new cookie with your uuid on it (as you said in your comments), then you can just do this in Express in response to any incoming request:

```
res.cookie('uuid', uuid);
```

Comment: I want to generate a cookie named `uuid`  when user visit any page in my application, when did I call this?

Comment: @roger - In any incoming request that you have an Express `app.get()` route handler for from the desired page or as middleware in `app.use()`.